# mysql query to display data using joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables I want to display datas which are not in table 2 but exist in table 1 and after listing the datas.I want to add those datas in table 2.
which join shall i use?please help me with the code

Comment: Please provide some more details and your code.

Comment: Actually ive two tables products and products_myob now i want to display all records which are in product_myob but not in products and after displaying records in the front end there is a button called update which will add the records in table products.

Comment: code is too long to post :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need no join at all. You want data from table1 where no entry *exists* in table2. So use the EXISTS clause.

```
select something 
from table1 
where not exists 
(
  select *
  from table2 
  where table2.somekey = table1.somekey
);
```

As to the insert:

```
insert into table2 (column names)
select something 
from table1 
where not exists
(
  select *
  from table2 
  where table2.somekey = table1.somekey
);
```